# Linq Join with Clone

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sequence of objects, whose type has many properties and I would like to join it with another sequence and set a value taking from the second sequence. But because there are many properties I do not prefer to create a new anonymous type by doing all those property assignments. Is there a better way to do this in a single linq query (having been trying un-successfully with let)

```
var x = from lt in legalTerms
join le in legalEntities on lt.LegalEntityCode equals le.Code
select new {a = lt.a, b = lt.b, c = le.c, d = lt.d .... z=lt.z} // don't like
```

I  need a sequence like legalTerms where the items have that one property updated from legalEntities 
Wish there was somehow a way to clone le and set that one property c = le.c without using reflection etc

Basically this is what I wonder is possible in a linq statement

```
        foreach (var lt in legalTerms)
        {
            foreach (var le in legalEntities)
            {
                if (le.Code == lt.LegalEntityCode)
                {
                    lt.LegalEntity = le.Name;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does "set a value taking from the second sequence" mean?

Comment: What's the alternative that you'd like to see rather than making all of these property assignments?

Comment: What do you mean by "clone `le` and set that one property"?

Comment: It means the items in the first sequence do not have that property initialized so based on the join condition I set the value using the items in the second sequence

Comment: So it's nothing to do with the anonymous sequence. You just want to assign some of the values from the `le` to the `lt` instance?

Comment: Yes, you could say that. I mentioned anonymous sequence as the most common example of what I have seen as examples on the web

Comment: The loops work. Why do you insist on using linq? Linq is intended for non-mutation. If you want to modify an existing object instead of instantiating a new one, then loops are the proper language construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this

```
var map = new Func<LegalTerm, LegalEntity, LegalTerm>((term, entity) =>
{
    term.LegalEntity = entity.Name;
    return term;
});

var query = from lt in legalTerms
            join le in legalEntities 
                on lt.Code equals le.LegalEntityCode
            select map(lt, le);
```

knowing that you have some sort of structures similar to those bellow

```
public class LegalTerm
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string LegalEntity { get; set; }
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }
}

public class LegalEntity
{
    public string LegalEntityCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```